# Geogebra Logo or custom-made logo

Tags: geogebra, icon

I can't find any already made icon for Geogebra.

Alternatively, I have it as a svg file that I know how to insert on a document.
How could I make it accessible for all my latex files without copying that svg in the current folder ?

Thank you

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te is related, that question talks about styles and classes but it works in the same way for images (for example `\includegraphics{example-image}` works from any document because there is a file `example-image.png` in the LaTeX search path as part of the `mwe` package)